# If datamart is logical division of datawarehouse , then what is it corresponding in a datalake?

Tags: bigdata, etl, snowflake-schema

If datamart is logical division of datawarehouse , then what is it corresponding in a datalake?
Also is there any design being followed in datalake like star or snowflake schema?

Answer (score 0):

The data lake concept is to have all kind of data available in a single place, so most of them is expected to not be fully organised, like logs or social media feeds, so there is not an equivalent concept of datamart.

Anyway it is useful to give also to a data lake some kind of organisation, but how to do is to you. An easy way, but maybe not so useful, is by source. I.e. all logs in a place, so.me. feeds in another and so on.

One very useful concept for a data lake is to be able to know what is there and how it is named, so data dictionaries are very useful both to find information and to understand it.